# Spark UDF to retrieve Last non null value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Input Dataset

```
 Dataset<Row> inputDS = spark.read.format("avro").path("hdfs://namenode:8020/..")
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |  time         | thingId       |     controller | module| variableName |  value |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |1554188264901  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |Value         |    5   |
 |1554188264901  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    7   |
 |1554188276412  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |Voltage       |    9   |
 |1554188276412  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    10  |  
 |1554188639406  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    6   |
 |1554188639407  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |Voltage       |    3   |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
```

Intermediate Dataset

```
 inputDS.createOrReplaceTempView("abc");
 Dataset<Row> intermediateDS<Row> =
 spark.sql("select time,thingId,controller,module,variableName,value,count(time) over (partition by time) as time_count from abc")
                                        .filter("time_count=1").drop("time_count");

 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |  time         | thingId       |     controller | module| variableName |  value |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |1554188639406  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    6   |
 |1554188639407  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |Voltage       |    3   |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
```

Intermediate Dataset is nothing but the time column which occurred only once like above.

Required Output Dataset

```
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |  time         | thingId       |     controller | module| variableName |  value |
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
 |1554188639406  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    6   |
 |1554188639406  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |Voltage       |    9   |  // last non null value for the set (thingId, controller, module) and variableName='Voltage'
 |1554188639407  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |Voltage       |    3   |  
 |1554188639407  |  0002019000000|        0       | 0     |SetPoint      |    10  |  // last non null value for the set (thingId, controller, module) and variableName='SetPoint'
 +---------------+---------------+----------------+-------+--------------+--------+
```

To get the required output I tried with UDF like below

```
 spark.udf().register("getLastvalue_udf",getValue,DataType.StringType);

 intermediateDS=intermediateDS.withColumn("Last_Value",callUDF("getLastvalue_udf",col("variableName")));

 UDF1<String,String> getValue = new UDF1<String,String>(){

 @Override
 public String call(String t1){

 String variableName="";

 if(t1=="SetPoint"){
 variableName="Voltage";
 }else{
 variableName="SetPoint";
 }

 String value = String.valueOf(spark.sql("SELECT LAST(value) OVER (order by time desc) as value from abc where "
  +" variableName="+ variableName +") limit 1")

 return value;
 }
```

but the `UDF` just returned `[value:String]`. `spark.sql()` doesn't working inside an UDF.

1.) How to obtain the Required Output from above UDF or suggest me with any other workaround.

2.) Is it possible to call spark sql inside map function ?
Thanks.

Comment: your comment "last non null value for the set (thingId, controller, module) and variableName='?'"
could you please explain it a little bit ?

Comment: @VikasKushwaha, "for the set" in the sense for every combinations in thingId,controller,module,variableName like `0001999000100,0,1,Voltage` is a set. I sorted it out using lag sql function kindly find the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lag](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#lag-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-int-) function solved the situation which returns values from a previous row in the table

Code below:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions;

WindowSpec lagWindow = Window.partitionBy("thingId","controller","module","variableName").orderBy("time");
DS.withColumn("value",when(col("value").equalTo(""),lag("value",1).over(lagWindow)).otherwise(col("value")));
```